# How to have Fuzzy Match on text filter in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, fuzzy-search

I have a text filter hooked up to a matrix such that when you enter a string into the text filter, it will filter the matrix to just those entries with a matching substring in the column associated with the filter.

This is great, but is there a way to do some sort of fuzzy match? Something perhaps where the filter measures the Levenshtein distance between the entered string and all entries in the column and filters down to those with distance < x?

The column is currently an amalgam of a few other columns, so the data looks like this (this is a single column, not multiple)

> APPLE WASHINGTON COMPUTER
>
> FACEBOOK MENLO SOCIAL
>
> BLIZZARD IRVINE COMPUTER

The current functionality would be if you searched "App" would match the first entry above and filter to just that. If you searched "Comp" it would return the first and third. I want it such that if you search "Aple" it would still return the first row, as currently it returns nothing.

Comment: Some sample data with expected output would help.

Comment: @mkRabbani added some detail